# ControlDesigner not active when dragging control from Toolbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to add designer support for my custom WinForms control, but it looks designer is only active when I already have instance created, not during drag'n'drop from Toolbox.

To show what I mean I've created simple control with designer:

```
[Designer(typeof(MyButtonDesigner))]
public class MyButton:Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        base.Size= new Size(50,50);
    }
}
class MyButtonDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    public override bool CanBeParentedTo(IDesigner parentDesigner)
    {
        return parentDesigner != null && parentDesigner.Component is Form;
    }
}
```

I'd like my control to by hosted only by form (user will be able to add control only to form, not to groupbox). When I drag control from Toolbox my validation logic is skipped, but when I try to move my control instance from form to groupbox I can see that drop is validated (as shown below)

[image]

I'm quite new to ControlDesigner so I'm not sure if this behavior is by design or can I change this so that my validation will work when dragging from Toolbox.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, but I don't think this should be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CanBeParentedTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.canbeparentedto(v=vs.110).aspx) method is not called when an item is dragged from the Toolbox onto the design surface.
You can create a custom [`ToolBoxItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.toolboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx) for your control and then override [`CreateComponentsCore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh3thah9(v=vs.110).aspx) method to prevent creating control when the parent is not `Form`. The `ToolBoxItem` will be used when dragging control from ToolBox and the `Designer` will be used when dragging control from design-surface.

```
//Add reference to  System.Drawing.dll then using
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
public class MyButtonToolBoxItem:ToolboxItem
{
    protected override IComponent[] CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host,
        System.Collections.IDictionary defaultValues)
    {
        if(defaultValues.Contains("Parent"))
        {
            var parent = defaultValues["Parent"] as Control;
            if(parent!=null && parent is Form)
                return base.CreateComponentsCore(host, defaultValues);
        }

        var svc = (IUIService)host.GetService(typeof(IUIService));
        if (svc != null) svc.ShowError("Can not host MyButton in this control");

        return null;
    }
}
```

To register the toolbox item for your control:

```
[ToolboxItem(typeof(MyButtonToolBoxItem))]
[Designer(typeof(MyButtonDesigner))]
public class MyButton : Button
```

As result, when you drag your control from toolbox and drop it on any container other than form, it shows a message to the user and nothing happens and it will not added to that parent. If you like, you can remove the messagebox.

Comment: Thank You so much, I never used ToolboxItem class, something I must read about. Everything works fine except one thing. When I drag item from toolbox to something else than form it isn't added (as expected) but mouse cursor still indicates I can drop it there. Can I change cursor to "No" because now it is bit confusing - user sees that he can drop control, but actually I'm preventing it.

Comment: You are welcome, currently as a solution, I decided to show a Visual Studio Error. I applied an edit to post.

Comment: Another workaround is `if (host.RootComponent is Form) defaultValues["Parent"] = host.RootComponent;` it changes the drop target to be `Form`. I prefer showing error message.

Comment: Thank You for looking to this again. I agree that showing error message is better than changing target. I'll leave this as so. Developer will see that error once, next time he'll remember :)